# Android Studio Gradle - A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugManifest'

Tags: android, android-studio

I already had this error months ago and the "solution" was to downgrade gradle. after a while for some reason I could use the latest version and everything worked.

Until now, I get this error massage again but can't downgrade gradle again because some of the latest plugins wouldn't work any more and I would have to downgrade them too.

I just want this pile of crap called android studio to work properly with their latest bs!

How can I solve this??

This is the error:

```
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugManifest' (type 'ProcessMultiApkApplicationManifest').
  - In plugin 'com.android.internal.version-check' type 'com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessMultiApkApplicationManifest' property 'mainMergedManifest' specifies file 'G:\projekte\ANDROID\xxxx\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml' which doesn't exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

and I also get a warning:

```
The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is deprecated. Please use this migration guide (https://goo.gle/kotlin-android-extensions-deprecation) to start working with View Binding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and the 'kotlin-parcelize' plugin.
```

When I "run" what is suggested I get:

[image]

It says some navigation.json can't be found what ever the hell this is

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem was because the project files were on a USB drive which was not ntfs, moving them to ntfs drive fixed it